# Find the k-th member of the recursive sequence

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have a recursive sequence: $a_n = 5a_{n - 1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3$, for $n > 1$. And I could return $k-th$ member in $O(\log{k})$ of sequence i.e. $a_k$.
I know how to get the formula of the $k-th$ member using the generating function method, but I need to find a more algorithmic solution.
For example, like this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834242/derivation-of-fibonacci-logn-time-sequence).

Comment: It should be $a_n = 5a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3$. Rihgt?

Comment: Yes, I fix it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_n     & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n+1} & a_n     & 0 \\
a_n     & a_{n-1} & 0 \\
1       & 1       & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore $a_k$ is the first element of the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{k-2}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2     & a_1 & 0 \\
a_1 & a_0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This only requires $O(\log k)$ matrix multiplications, each of which can be done using a constant amount of arithmetic operations on scalars.